# Which language idioms/paradigms/features make it hard to add support for "type providers"?

Tags: c#, database, f#, clr, language-design

F# 3.0 has added [type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

I wonder if it is possible to add this language feature to other languages running on the CLR like C# or if this feature only works well in a more functional/less OO programming style?

Comment: It would be more interesting to ask about language features that makes this sort of things easier to implement. And the answer is: compilation time metaprogramming (as in Lisp, MetaOCaml, Nemerle, Template Haskell, etc.). I wonder why they've implemented type providers as a primitive in F#, instead of allowing a more generic solution. And this metaprogramming thing is entirely orthogonal to OO, functional, imperative, whatsoever, you can play this game with any possible language.

Comment: @SK-logic - I think that type providers _are_ a form of compile time metaprogramming.  Besides, the "more general" solutions that you praise have their own set of tradeoffs too.  For instance, MetaOCaml makes the type system more complex by introducing the idea of staging (and as far as I know allows quoting/splicing/running only expressions, not type definitions).

Comment: @kvb, yes, they are indeed a form of compile time metaprogramming. But I would prefer to have a full-blown generic metaprogramming instead of a bunch of various specific "forms" of it. And, yes, MetaOCaml is not ideal - there are ways of doing the same thing much, much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Brian and Tomas point out, there's nothing particularly "functional" about this feature. It's just a particularly slick way to provide metadata to the compiler.

The C# design team has been kicking around ideas like this for a long time. There was a proposal a few years before I joined the C# team for a feature that was going to be called "type blueprints" (or something like that) whereby a combination of XML documents, XML schema and custom code that proffered up type metadata could be used by the C# compiler. I don't recall the details and it never came to fruition, obviously. (Though it did influence the design and the implementation of the Visual Studio Tools for Office document format, which I was working on at the time.)

In any event, we have no plans on the immediate horizon for adding such a feature to C#, but we are watching with great interest to see if it does a good job of solving customer problems in F#.

(As always, Eric's musings about possible future features of unnannounced and entirely hypothetical products are for entertainment purposes only.)

Comment: I would say you absolutely need to improve the dependency compilation model. this is all too implicit, and not composable. i guess this hinders a lot of evolution I can imagine to your platform.

Answer (score 8):

As Tomas says, it is theoretically straightforward to add this kind of feature to any statically-typed language (though still a lot of grunt-work).

I am not a meta-programming expert, but @SK-logic asks why not a general compile-time meta-programming system instead, and I shall try to answer.  I don't think you can easily achieve what you can do with F# type providers using meta-programming, because F# type providers can be lazy and dynamically interactive at design-time.  Let's give an example that Don has demo-ed in one of his earlier videos: a [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) type provider.  Freebase is kind of like a schematized, programmable wikipedia, it has data on everything.  So you can end up writing code along the lines of

```
for e in Freebase.Science.``Chemical Elements`` do
    printfn "%d: %s - %s" e.``Atomic number`` e.Name e.Discoverer.Name
```

or whatnot (I don't have the exact code offhand), but just as easily write code that gets information about baseball statistics, or when famous actors have been in drug rehab facilities, or a zillion other types of information available through Freebase.

From an implementation point-of-view, it is infeasible to generate a schema for all of Freebase and bring it into .NET a-priori; you can't just do one compile-time step at the beginning to set all this up. You *can* do this for small data sources, and in fact many other type providers use this strategy, e.g. a SQL type provider gets pointed at a database, and generates .NET types for all the types in that database.  But this strategy does *not* work for large cloud data stores like Freebase, because there are too many interrelated types (if you tried to generate .NET metadata for all of Freebase, you'd find that there are so many millions of types (one of which is `ChemicalElement` with `AtomicNumber` and `Discoverer` and `Name` and many other fields, but there are literally millions of such types) that you need more memory than is available to a 32-bit .NET process just to represent the entire type schema.

So the F# type-provider strategy is an API architecture that allows type providers to supply information on-demand, running at design-time within the IDE.  Until you type e.g. `Freebase.Science.`, the type provider does not need to know about the entities under the science categories, but once you do press `.` after `Science`, then the type provider can go and query the APIs to learn one-more-level of the overall schema, to know what categories exist under Science, one of which is `ChemicalElements`.  And then as you try to "dot into" one of those, it will discover that elements have atomic numbers and what-not.  So the type provider lazily fetches just enough of the overall schema to deal with the exact code the user happens to be typing into the editor at that moment in time.  As a result, the user still has the freedom to explore any part of the universe of information, but any one source code file or interactive session will only explore a tiny fraction of what is available.  When it comes time to compile/codegen, the compiler need only generate enough code to accomodate exactly the bits that the user has actually used in his code, rather than the potentially huge runtime bits to afford the possibility of talking to the whole data store.

(Maybe you can do that with some of today's meta-programming facilities now, I don't know, but the ones I learned about in school a long while back could not have easily handled this.)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that type information will be generated _only_ for types explicitly referenced in code? Does that mean recursively traversing your entire "universe of data" is impossible?

Comment: The type provider can choose to do what it likes, but the compiler is only going to instantiate it with its static parameters, and then call into it 'on-demand'.  So e.g. the SQLConnection provider in the box just generates the entire schema as .Net types up-front, whereas a Freebase provider clearly must wait until the compiler calls it on-demand to do a small amount of work with each call.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any technical reason why something like type providers couldn't be added to C# or similar languages. The only family of langauges that make it difficult to add type providers (in a similar way as in F#) are *dynamically typed languages*.

F# type providers rely on the fact that the type information that are generated by the provider nicely propagate through the program and the editor can use them to show useful IntelliSense. In dynamically typed languages, this would require more elaborate IDE support (and "type providers" for dynamic langauges reduce to just IDE or IntelliSense).

Why are they implemented directly as a feature of F#? I think the meta-programming system would have to be really complex (note that the types are not *actually* generated) to support this. The other things that could be done using it wouldn't contribute to the F# language that much (they would only make it too complex, which is a bad thing). However, you could get similar thing if you had some sort of compiler extensibility.

In fact, I think this is how the C# team will add something like type providers in the future (they talked about compiler extensibility for some time now).

Comment: I doubt that a metaprogramming subsystem can be complex. In fact, any language with a decent metaprogramming is much, much simpler than a monolithic language, as it allows to define language features in a library instead of a compiler core. See how small the core language of Nemerle is, for example.

Comment: Metaprogramming is no requirement for that.

Comment: @SK-logic - keep in mind that the meta part of the program needs to be called from the IDE, possibly with some security restrictions. Also it cannot just "generate" all types from the http://www.programmableweb.com/, because it wouldn't have enough memory for that. It needs to generate types lazily. The whole meta-system would still have to compile to .NET though... I'm sure this would take more development than one version of F#.

Comment: @Tomas Petricek, still, I doubt that it is a fundamental problem. It is entirely up to your implementation of a type fetching macro itself, nothing stops you from doing it lazily, and .NET is quite suitable for this kind of code generation.